# how to handle loop for joining channel to not get eror AuthKeyDuplicatedError in Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using Telethon with a loop for joining telegram accounts to different channel . i have to use proxy and change IP constantly because of my country (Telegram in banned in our country) but after one-two loop i start to get this error :

```
AuthKeyDuplicatedError:The authorization key (session file) was used under two different IP addresses simultaneously, and can no longer be used. Use the same session exclusively, or use different sessions.
```

i use `client.connect()` for connect and `client.disconnect()` to close . i don't know what should i use instead of them! . my code is dirty but something like this :

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
while True:
 f = open('profiles.txt', "r")
 profiles = f.readlines()
 for index,phone_number in enumerate(profiles, start=1):
        phone_number=phone_number.replace("\n","")
        client = TelegramClient(StringSession(phone_number), api_id, api_hash,proxy=(socks.SOCKS5,'127.0.0.1', 9150)) #using Tor proxy 
        client.connect()
        #join to channel 
        client.disconnect()
```

** it is not syntax error